graphql codegen schemas and types export
I am trying to use graphql-codegen in order to get all different types and schemas from my graphql api, i am able to create a single file which has all the data but it is very large.
I want to be able to generate this but with separate files, one for each schema.
Let's say I have 2 entities and endpoints for clients and fleets. I would like the codegen to produce 2 different files: clients-types.ts and fleets-types.ts.
I have this code inside codegen.ts:
import { CodegenConfig } from "@graphql-codegen/cli";

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: "https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index",
  generates: {
    // Base types file containing all types from your schema
    "gra/types.ts": {
      plugins: ["typescript"],
    },
    // Optional: Generate additional types for inputs (if needed)
    "gra/": {
      preset: "near-operation-file",
      presetConfig: {
        extension: ".generated.ts",
        baseTypesPath: "types.ts",
      },
      plugins: ["typescript-operations"],
      config: {
        useTypeImports: true, // Use type imports for better syntax
      },
    },
  },
};

export default config;


The "gra/types.ts" part is working and i get a full file with all the types available from the schema, but the second part ("near-operation-file") does nothing.
How can I make these types into separate files?
